# Laravel Cashier: Invalid Request, No such customer

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.1, laravel-cashier

I am trying to implement what mentioned [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php) but getting error:

```
Array ([type] => invalid_request_error [message] => No such customer: 92 [param] => customer)
```

I am using Laravel Cashier:

```
$user = User::find($current_user_id);

if ($user->charge(100, [
    'customer' => 92,
    'source'      => $token,
    'description' => "Testing Payment Deduction for Brief"
])
) {
    print "Awesome";
} else {
    print "it failed";
}
```

Using this code to create customer fails as it trie to create a record in `users` table which does not need as I already have a user created:

```
        $customer = $user->create(array(
            'email' => 'customer@example.com',
            'card'  => $token
        ));
```

How can I send my existing customer ID and email to Stripe?

Comment: the customer's id would be $customer->id, where are you getting 92 from?

Comment: @MatthewArkin the second snippet which supposes to return `id` is actually creating a user in `users` table. I don't need this.

Comment: @MatthewArkin I was implementing what mentioned here: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php

Comment: Do you want to save the customer in stripe as well to charge them in the future or are you only creating the charge once?

Comment: I do not want subscription model but I do want to have customer information saved as my system is pay on go for registered customer

Comment: So you do want to be creating a stripe customer and adding the customer's ID to your database (customer->id). Their stripe customer id is in the format of "cus_<rest of id>" that is the id you should be sending as the customer field in the charge, not 92

Comment: @MatthewArkin Thank for pointing out but `create()` method within `Laravel` create a local db record too which is killing.

Answer (score 0):

This issues erupts only due to one reason and that is token generated by following function.

**Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler)**

in **stripeResponseHandler(status, response)** 
**response.id** is the token value. so please use this token to create subscription or whatever... Thanks